# Differential equation: capacitor

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The voltage of a capacitor can be described with the differential equation $ \frac {du} {dt} + \frac {1} {RC} u = 0$ where the voltage is u(t) at the time t.

Solve the differential equation:

Don't really know how to solve this one. Would appreciate tips/hints on how to tackle differential equations like this in general.

Comment: This is the most basic first order homogeneous constant coefficient differential equation. Look in any engineering maths textbook.

Comment: A usual idea for a homogenous equation with constant coefficients is to try an exponential solution $u=e^{\lambda t}$. On the other hand since it's first order (one derivative) you can try separate the variables, bring $u$'s to one side $t$'s to the other

Comment: Yeah, I misread the question and didn't realise that R and C were constants. Thus my confusion. I'll leave the question be though because someone might find it useful.

Comment: If you want to leave it, that's fine by me.  It is worth noting that this example exhibits exponential *decay* because $\lambda = -1/RC$ is negative.  Whatever (voltage) charge is initial placed on the capacitor, it will be discharged more quickly with lower resistance $R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac {du} {dt} + \frac {1} {RC} u = 0$$
$$\frac {du} {dt} =- \frac {u} {RC} $$
$$\frac {du} {u} =- \frac {dt} {RC}  $$
Integrate 
$$\int \frac {du} {u} =-\int  \frac {dt} {RC}  $$
$$\ln(u)=- \frac {t} {RC} +K $$
$$u(t)=Ke^{- \frac {t} {RC}}  $$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:This is equivalent to $\frac{(\frac{du}{dt})}{u}=-1/RC$. Now LHS is just $\frac{d \log u}{dt}$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $R$ and $C$ are constant this has the solution

$$u(t) = e^{-t\frac{1}{RC}}$$

This is a first-order homogeneous ODE, for which general solutions are easily availble. [Khan Academy has a good tutorial, for example.](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/first-order-differential-equations)